# Safe to modify settings.SITE_ID from middleware in Django?

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-sites

I have modified the multihost.py middleware I found at http://effbot.org/zone/django-multihost.htm to set the settings.SITE_ID dynamically, but have some concerns that I may have just left the reservation.

Most examples I have found for multiple domain hosting have been setup with multiple settings.py files hardcoded to their respective SITE_IDs.

Have I created a fix with a fatal flaw here? Will changing this value dynamically bite me on the a**.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class MultiHostMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            host_raw = request.META["HTTP_HOST"]
            colon = host_raw.find(':')
            if colon > -1:
                host = host_raw[0:colon]
            else:
                host = host_raw

            s = Site.objects.get(domain=host)
            if s:
                settings.SITE_ID = s.id

        except KeyError:
            pass # use default urlconf (settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
```

For the curious this is up and running so far, but has not stood up to actual traffic.

Comment: No idea whether that will work, but I wonder whether using `urlparse` would be better for getting the hostname (http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html).

Comment: Additional information, this code has been in place on a 2 domain site for about a week now with no apparent glitches. Fairly low traffic but I think the concept holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short, official answer is [you're not supposed to do this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime), though the docs don't really explain why not.

If you're using a threaded server, I'd be concerned about a race condition.  This should be quite simple to test; just put a call to `sleep()` in one view, then return an `HttpResponse` with the name of the current site. While the first view is sleeping, hit a different view on a different domain.

If you use prefork, I don't imagine that this would cause any problems.  I've used this approach with matplotlib, since it's easiest to set graph properties by changing global configuration with `matplotlib.rcParams.update()`.  I use prefork fcgi, so I can safely assume that each request has the whole process to itself (folks, please correct me if I'm wrong).

**Edit**: I think you can do what you want using [RequestSite](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/sites/#requestsite-objects) by *disabling* the `sites` application. James Bennett's [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/d36a38202ee3/registration/backends/default/__init__.py#cl-49), for example, instantiates a `RequestSite` object in that case, which extracts the hostname from the request object.